# Solving the o.d.e. $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble working out this following ODE:$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{y}$$

I know that the equation is homogenous and therefore we are able to solve it by subbing $v=\frac{y}{x}$ but also looking for a way to solve by substituting $v=x^2+y^2$.

This is my first time using MSE so please let me know if I'm asking questions in the correct way or how i can format them better :)

Comment: You did get two answers that make use of $v=x^2+y^2$, but is there a reason you expected that substitution to work?

Comment: @Teepeemm Seemed like a reasonable substitution to simplify the DE, but was getting some transposition errors on my end. Answers helped me out heaps:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{y}$$
$$y'y=-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$y'y+x=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$2y'y+2x=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$(y^2+x^2)'=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
Now substitute $v=x^2+y^2$ and separate and integrate the  DE.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment: Converting to polar coordinates via $(x, y) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$---in which case the desired quantity $x^2 + y^2$ is just $r^2$---gives $$\sin \theta \frac{dr}{d\theta} + (1 + \cos \theta) r = 0,$$ so $$r = \frac{C}{1 - \cos \theta},$$ which we might recognize as [parabolas with axis the $x$-axis and focus at the origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section). Converting back to Cartesian coordinates gives $$y^2 = C(2 x + C).$$ Notice that we should exclude the degenerate solution $y = 0$ (given by $C = 0$), which does not satisfy the original equation, where $y$ appeared in a denominator.